# NullPointerException at org.chromium.media.AudioManagerAndroid.hasUsbAudioCommInterface(AudioManagerAndroid.java:1224)

Tags: android, audio, webview, chromium

My app uses a `WebView` to display some content. Some day I started to receive the following error from my users:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error receiving broadcast Intent { act=android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED flg=0x10 pkg=com.chessking.android.learn.ctforbeginners } in org.chromium.media.AudioManagerAndroid$5@13883a1
       at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:891)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5420)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)

Caused by java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.hardware.usb.UsbDevice.getInterfaceCount()' on a null object reference
       at org.chromium.media.AudioManagerAndroid.hasUsbAudioCommInterface(AudioManagerAndroid.java:1224)
       at org.chromium.media.AudioManagerAndroid.access$1200(AudioManagerAndroid.java:43)
       at org.chromium.media.AudioManagerAndroid$5.onReceive(AudioManagerAndroid.java:1254)
       at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:881)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5420)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

I've looked at AudioManagerAndroid.java code, the error is in line

`if (!hasUsbAudioCommInterface(device)) return;`

`device` is null:

```
 .... 
 mUsbAudioReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                UsbDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(UsbManager.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                if (DEBUG) {
                    logd("UsbDeviceBroadcastReceiver.onReceive: a= " + intent.getAction()
                            + ", Device: " + device.toString());
                }
                // Not a USB audio device.
                if (!hasUsbAudioCommInterface(device)) return;
 ....
```

How can I avoid the problem without changing chromium sources? My `WebView` never use audio. Is there a way to do not subscribe for Audio events?

Comment: Having exactly the same error and cannot find anything related to my code. Did you find a solution or face this problem again?

Comment: Looks like after upgrading dependencies the problem went away.

Comment: Hey Baki..now did you find any solution or what's the problem?